# Jquery tab control is not working when i using it in content page

Tags: asp.net, css, jquery-ui

I have a master page in an asp.net web application and default.aspx is the content page of the master page.

I am using jQuery tab in default.aspx and it is not working when i run the application:  the styles of the ui-tabs has come but I am not able to click on the tab.

When i try the same thing in master page itself, the tab control is working fine i mean i can able to click on the tab which is showing the appropriate content of the tab container

I'm using jQuery UI

```
 <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/tab/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
   <div id="quicksearch">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Quick Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Quick Register</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <h1>
                Quick search</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <h1>
                Quick Register</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

function i'm using to select the tab:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

what would be the problem here?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: actually there is no errors, but the click function for the tab is not working

Comment: i mean i'not able to select the tabs by mouse click, please figure it out

Comment: Hi i have found the root of the problem. Actually the problem is that if i am using this Div(class=Content) in the master page, then the tab action is not working.  <div class="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ChildPageContents" runat="server">
        

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div> if i remove the class for the div then the tab is working fine.... actually that content class in stylesheet is used as design that is how the content page's contents should appear in between and footer in the master page. Thats why i use that div(class= content) in the master page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id will be mangled by asp.net.Reference your tab like this using a class selector which will remain untouched when your page is rendered.

**Master page** in the head section

your  jquery imports here

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function ()
    {
    //initialization code
     $(".tabs" ).tabs();
     }
</script>
```

and then in you content page

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Quick Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Quick Register</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <h1>
            Quick search</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <h1>
            Quick Register</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above links work for me as of writing this article.Zipped demo [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/81286708/WebSite7.zip)

[image]

Comment: then how can i overcome this problem,because i have to use the jquery tab in content page which will added to the master page when the page is rendered to html?

Comment: Put the initialization code on the parent page.That css class will be will be readily available in the DOM.

Comment: hi Abide Masaraure, actually i'm new to use this master page and jquery in my projects, so could you please give me a clear explanation  for what i have to do here?  what is initialization code? //.That css class will be will be readily available in the DOM. // what does it mean ?

Comment: please be patient to help me

Comment: if i change the  div's id to class, tab styles doesn't come

Comment: You are  supposed to change only one div id to class, the parent div.Then use the css class selector in the initialization as I have shown.I am zipping a demo for you.

Comment: I have updated my answer again .DOM means 'document object model' and have sandwiched the initialization code in a dom ready function and it works.See attached demo

Comment: Thanks abide... I am out of office at the moment and will check it out tomorrow.... If I can not resolve the problem can I send me application to you.... So that you can rectify the error.... It would be helpful for me for my entire project since I have to use tab control in numerous pages

Comment: Thank you very much.... Will let you know my status tomorrow..... Could you send me mail to Yogesh.ktm@gmail.com so that i can send my application

Comment: Hi i have found the root of the problem.

Comment: Hi i have found the root of the problem. Actually the problem is that if i am using this Div(class=Content) in the master page, then the tab action is not working.  <div class="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ChildPageContents" runat="server">
        

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div> if i remove the class for the div then the tab is working fine.... actually that content class in stylesheet is used as design that is how the content page's contents should appear in between and footer in the master page. Thats why i use that div(class= content) in the master page.

Answer (score 0):

@AbideMasaraure is solved my problem.... thousands of thanks to him.... 
The problem is negative z-index in content class in stylesheet